# recibir parametros de un listview

Tags: android

tengo una actividad que con una lista de  productos, para cada onclick que hago sobre cada elemento de esa lista, manda 2 parametros en una otra actividad para amar otra lista segun los elementos seleccionados en la primera lista ... lo que quiero hacer es un botton que me permite de ver la lista en la segunga actividad.... sin que esa segunda actividad espera los  2 parametros.
(ME TIENE QUE MONSTRAR LA LISTA NO MAS...) ahi esta mi codigo..

```
  case R.id.Carrito:
                String token=get.doInBackground().toString();
            TextView texto;
            texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
            String text2 = texto.getText().toString();
            Intent intent2 = null;intent2= new Intent(busqueda.this,Compra.class);
            intent2.putExtra("TOKENS", datas);
            intent2.putExtra("CODI", text2);
           // startActivity(intent2);
            Toast.makeText(busqueda.this,"Producto fue agregado...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return   super.onContextItemSelected(item);
```

Ahi esta el codigo de la segunda que reciba y lee loo parametros..

```
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        prod = new ArrayList<>();
        lista_eligida = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_eligida);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String linked = null;
        String coded = null;


        if (extras != null) {
            linked = extras.getString("TOKENS");
            coded = extras.getString("CODI");
        }
            // link.setText(linked);
            //code.setText(coded);
            String url = "http://www.air-intra.com/apps/air-app/agregar.php?token=" + linked + "&codiart=" + coded + "";
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            JSONObject jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PRR");
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                    String des = c.getString("descrip");
                    String prec = c.getString("precio");
                    // String garb = c.getString("fisicolug");

                    HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();

                    contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                    contacto.put("descrip", des);
                    contacto.put("precio", prec);
                    //contact.put("fisicolug", garb);

                    prod.add(contacto);

                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {

            }


        return null;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result){
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, prod,
                    R.layout.item_carrito, new String[]{"codigo", "descrip", "precio"},
                    new int[]{R.id.tvcode, R.id.tvdescrip, R.id.tvprec});
            lista_eligida.setAdapter(adapter);

            //registerForContextMenu(lista_eligida);
            //  registerForContextMenu(textView);

        }
```

Comment: revisa tu ortografía, es algo complicado de entender, ¿quieres ver la lista en otra actividad?

Comment: mil disculpa amigo que no hablo español, y ahora lo estoy leyendo de nuevo ,vi que es complicado de entender lo que escribí...
Si quiero ver la lista de los productos seleccionados en la otra actividad..
Gracias

Comment: si no hablas español, ¿no es más fácil que publiques la pregunta en el sitio en inglés de StackOverflow?

Comment: gracias por el consejo